# How to add header using Filehelper with DataTableToCSV

Tags: .net, filehelpers

I am using:

```
DataTableToCSV(datatable,filepath)
```

to create a CSV file. Which is generating perfect CSV. Now how do I add column names when using DataTableToCSV?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
[DelimitedRecord(","), IgnoreFirst(1)]
public class Person
{
    // Must specify FieldOrder too
    [FieldOrder(1), FieldTitle("Name")]
    string name;

    [FieldOrder(2), FieldTitle("Age")]
    int age;
}

...

var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Person>
{
    HeaderText = typeof(Person).GetCsvHeader()
};

...

engine.WriteFile(@"C:\people.csv", people);
```

reference to https://gist.github.com/1391429

Comment: I have a filehelper.dll, where to add this gist ?

Comment: Please look into the following link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12170/FileHelpers-v-Delimited-CSV-or-Fixed-Data-Impor